# Can I parse my JSON data like this?

Tags: java, json, gson

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(cList);

JSONArray jasonlist = new JSONArray(json);

Map<String, Object> obj = new HashMap<>();

String dob1 = (String)obj.get("createdDate");
Date dtDob = new Date(dob1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String  newDate = sdf.format(dtDob);

obj.put("companymasterdata", jasonlist);
obj.put("EVENTNAME", "COMPANY_DATA");
obj.put("SOURCENAME", "COMPANY_KAFKA");
```

I just want to know whether my "createdDate" is parsed or if it throws runtime errors.

Comment: Forgive me , but at line : `String dob1 = (String)obj.get("createdDate");` Obj is an empty `Map` right?

Comment: yes , obj is MAP object where i am adding key and value pairs

Comment: But , you're trying to get value from it for key `createdDate` ?

Comment: Why not try to run your code (after you fixed the obvious bug) and see if the formatting works?

Comment: yes @MadhanVaradhodiyil its a key inside an object ( obj )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you create an empty map, if you attempt to read `"createdDate"` you will get `null` as a result. This won't throw any exception.

However, in the next line you want to initialize a new `Date` object and pass `dob1` (which is still always `null`). This will cause an `IllegalArgumentException` to be thrown.

You could easily find all that out yourself by simply executing your code.